# why this " TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" is rising for the below code for finding the minimum cost path of a grid?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

```
def minPathSum(grid):
    m=len(grid)
    n=len(grid[0])
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        grid[0][i]+=grid[0][i-1]
    
    for j in range(1,m):
        grid[j][0]+=grid[j-1][0]
        
    for i in range(1,m):
        for j in range(1,n):
            grid[i,j]+=min(grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1]) // This is where the error is happening
            
    return grid[m][n]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
grid[i,j]+=min(grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1])
```

`grid[i, j]` is wrong. This is not a numpy array. You have to do `grid[i][j]`.

```
grid[i][j]+=min(grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1])
```

This should work.